# How do I populate sourceInfo in SSM Association using TerraForm

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am building a very basic Systems Manager Association in TerraForm but I do not understand what the sourceInfo field is asking for.  It requires a string but even simple strings like "test" cause it to reject the input.

```
resource "aws_ssm_association" "sslscanssm" {
  name             = "AWS-RunInspecChecks"
  association_name = "test"

  targets = {
    key    = "tag:os"
    values = ["linux"]
  }

  parameters {
    sourceType = "GitHub"

    sourceInfo = "{"owner":"awslabs","repository":"amazon-ssm","path":"Compliance/InSpec/PortCheck","getOptions":"branch:master"}" 
    #^this line doesn't work
    #sourceInfo = "test"
    #^this line doesn't work either



  }
}
```

Comment: This was a simple syntax error but I keep the question here since explanation of the syntax rules for this terraform are sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of escaping all of your strings you could also use the [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#jsonencode-value-) function to turn a map into the JSON you want:

```
locals {
  source_info = {
    owner      = "awslabs"
    repository = "amazon-ssm"
    path       = "Compliance/InSpec/PortCheck"
    getOptions = "branch:master"
  }
}

resource "aws_ssm_association" "sslscanssm" {
  name             = "AWS-RunInspecChecks"
  association_name = "test"

  targets = {
    key    = "tag:os"
    values = ["linux"]
  }

  parameters {
    sourceType = "GitHub"

    sourceInfo = "${jsonencode(local.source_info)}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware sourceInfo expects parentheses and all inner double quotes to be escaped or it won't work.

```
resource "aws_ssm_association" "sslscanssm" {
  name             = "AWS-RunInspecChecks"
  association_name = "test"

  targets = {
    key    = "tag:os"
    values = ["linux"]
  }

  parameters {
    sourceType = "GitHub"

    sourceInfo = "{\"owner\":\"awslabs\",\"repository\":\"amazon-ssm\",\"path\":\"Compliance/InSpec/PortCheck\",\"getOptions\":\"branch:master\"}"


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the code shared (no equal sign after targets but after parameters). The correct syntax of the resource is :

```
resource "aws_ssm_association" "sslscanssm" {
  name             = "AWS-RunInspecChecks"
  association_name = "test"

  targets {
    key    = "tag:os"
    values = ["linux"]
  }

  parameters = {
    sourceType = "GitHub"

    sourceInfo = "${jsonencode(local.source_info)}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice.It worked for my issue